# Angular 2 with routing inside a CoreModule

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am studying angular 2 and had the idea to move the application menu component into a core folder and create a core module, my initial tests were not successful. Is it possible to do that? I must create a menu.routing.ts or keep the app.routing.ts? How do the AppModule and CoreModule?

Update:

Below is an example in Plunker the code I'm testing

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/cfu3fu0SRxdTjWOJ624A?p=preview]
```

You can see that routerLink are not rendering the href in the sidebar, this is my problem!

Comment: Can you show the code and error?

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray please see the update in the first post

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a menu.routing.ts . What you need is a core.module.ts that imports your menu.component.ts and then in your app.module.ts you would import your core.module.ts

So you will have something like this in your core.module.ts

```
import { MenuComponent }   from './menu.component';
@NgModule({

declarations: [
    ...
    MenuComponent
   ...
]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

And then in your app.module.ts you will have:

```
import { CoreModule }    from './core/core.module';

@NgModule({

imports: [
    ...
    CoreModule,
]
})
```

I saw that the question was asked a while ago, but I hope this can help someone else. :)